Azure Lighthouse - Assigning IAM permissions to users
Aloha, all:
My MSP team and I have been using both Azure and M365 Lighthouse for a few months now. Now we're pretty comfortable with it, we've an ongoing project to remove all our native accounts from customer environments.
Going through the benefits and drawbacks of removing them, we came to the conclusion that the key functionality we're missing is the ability to assign IAM roles to customer resources. Azure Lighthouse templates can't assign the below roles, and these roles have the ability to manage roles access
8e3af657-a8ff-443c-a75c-2fe8c4bcb635    Owner
f58310d9-a9f6-439a-9e8d-f62e7b41a168    Role Based Access Control Administrator
18d7d88d-d35e-4fb5-a5c3-7773c20a72d9    User Access Administrator
Let's say a customer need a new LAW set up and want to give a specific Entra group "Log Analytics Contributor" for the resource. We can create the Workspace with Contributor (Highest Azure Lighthouse permission), but I don't know how we'd assign permissions to the workspace.
I then though about using M365 Lighthouse to hop into the customer's Entra ID and grant GA access to manage Subscriptions (Added below), but the option is greyed out
enter image description here
Has anyone else encountered this? What's does everyone else do in situations like this?

To assign Azure roles, the signed-in user must have either Owner or User Access Administrator roles under Azure subscription.
The option to elevate access will be greyed out if the signed-in user does not have "Global Administrator" access under the tenant like this:

To enable that option, make sure to login with user having "Global Administrator" role under the tenant.
In my case, I have user named Sri having "Global Administrator" role like this:

When I signed in with user having "Global Administrator" role, option to elevate access enabled successfully like this:

Enabling above option will assign "User Access Administrator" role to signed-in user under root scope like this:

With this role, signed-in user will have access to assign Azure roles to users at any scope.
